# When I upload file to MySQL using Laravel, there are two separated lines in my database table for each request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm working on a Laravel web application that should upload .pdf files from a form to database, with some specific information inserted by the user in the same form where he uploads the file. Everything works perfectly, but in the table on my database, I have two separated rows created. First one contains just file_name (Original Client name) and file_size (Original Client size), but other form information set to their default values (NULL), in the second row I have the opposite, additional form data that is set correctly, but the file_name and file_size are set to default (NULL) here is my function in controller block

```php
public function auteurAdd(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->except(['_token']);
    $conference = new Conference();
    $conference->titre = $parameters['titre'];
    $conference->theme = $parameters['theme'];
    $conference->track = $parameters['track'];

    // upload file into database
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filesize = $request->file->getClientSize();
        $file = new Conference;
        $file->file_name = $filename;
        $file->file_size = $filesize;
        $file->save();
    }
    $conference->save();

    return redirect()->route('auteurHome');
}
```

and this is the form

```php
<form method="post" action="{{route('auteurAdd')}}" class="text-center border border-light p-5"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <p class="h4 mb-4">Upload d'une conférence</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="titre" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Titre"/>
        <input name="theme" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Thème"/>
        <input name="track" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Track"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded float-left">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block my-4" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove `$file = new Conference;` and use `$conference` instead of `$file`. Also remove `$file->save();`. If that works, we can close the question as "Typo".

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
public function auteurAdd(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->except(['_token']);
    $conference = new Conference();
    $conference->titre = $parameters['titre'];
    $conference->theme = $parameters['theme'];
    $conference->track = $parameters['track'];

    // upload file into database
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filesize = $request->file->getClientSize();
        $conference->file_name = $filename;
        $conference->file_size = $filesize;
    }
    $conference->save();

    return redirect()->route('auteurHome');
}
```